# Generalized angle sum identity for $\arctan$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The angle sum  identity for arctan is:

$$\arctan (\alpha)+\arctan(\beta)=\arctan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{1-\alpha\beta}\right)$$

I was wondering if there exists a relationship for any linear combination of $\arctan$ functions:

$$A\arctan (\alpha)+B\arctan(\beta)$$

$A>0, B>0$ and both real numbers.

Comment: Hint: $\arctan(\alpha)=\operatorname{arg}(1+i\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{arg}(z\cdot w)=\operatorname{arg}(z)+\operatorname{arg}(w).$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So $a \arctan(\alpha)=\arctan\left(\frac{\alpha+\sin(a)}{1+\cos(a)}\right)$?

Comment: no. But for instance: $$2\arctan\alpha = \arctan \alpha +\arctan \alpha =\arctan\frac{2\alpha}{1-\alpha^2}$$ and $$3\arctan\alpha = \arctan\frac{\alpha^2-3\alpha}{3\alpha^2-1}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But what if $a$ and $b$ are not integers?

Comment: I am not aware of a linear combination of arctan in the same way that we have $c_1\cos(\omega t)+c_2\sin(\omega t)=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$. The best I know of is what Jack D'Aurizio wrote with $2\arctan(t)=\arctan(t)+\arctan(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Yes, such a formula indeed exists:

https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/16/03/03/

**Old post**

I know this question has been asked a long time ago, but I figured this would still be of use. There must be such a formula for a linear combination of $\arctan$s! I don't know what exactly it looks like, but I accidentally came across this which is similar (long, painful way to get there at all, but anyway):

These two expressions (maybe someone else can format more nicely, sorry:) Mathematica code at the end)

$$A:=\frac{1}{2 a^{3/2}}
\\\left(\frac{ \left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}-2 a+b\right) \sqrt{(b-a) \left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}+2 a+b\right)} \arctan\left(\frac{b \left(\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a+b}\right) \tan \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+\sqrt{a}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a+b}\right) \sqrt{(b-a) \left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}+2 a+b\right)}}\right)}{b \left(\sqrt{a+b}+3 \sqrt{a}\right)}\\
-\frac{ \left(b-2 \left(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}+a\right)\right) \sqrt{(b-a) \left(-2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}+2 a+b\right)} \arctan\left(\frac{b \left(\left(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}\right) \tan \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+\sqrt{a}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}\right) \sqrt{(b-a) \left(-2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a+b}+2 a+b\right)}}\right)}{b \left(\sqrt{a+b}-3 \sqrt{a}\right)}\right)$$

$$B:=-\frac{\sqrt{b-a} \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b-a}} (\sin (\phi)+\cos (\phi))\right)}{2 a^{3/2}}$$

don't look very similar. However, deriving them with Mathematica by $\phi$ yields the same expression

$$\frac{(a-b) (\cos (\phi)-\sin (\phi))}{2 a (a \sin (2 \phi)+b)}.$$

Consequently, I think that $A$ and $B$ differ by a constant, if at all.

What strikes me is that both the coefficients and the arguments to the $\arctan$s seem to contain complex conjugate-like terms everywhere, for example $\sqrt{a+b}-3 \sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{a+b}+3 \sqrt{a}$ in the denominators. Maybe someone else can resolve the mystery and come up with a linear combination formula for $\arctan$s?

These two links are also quite insightful on such a linear combination :

[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54856/expand-2fx-to-fxfx-simplify-sums-of-arctan), [2](https://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=3703962&postcount=3)

Mathematica code:

```
FullSimplify[D[((2 (-2 a+b+2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b]) Sqrt[(-a+b) (2 a+b+2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b])] ArcTan[(b (Sqrt[a]+(Sqrt[a]-Sqrt[a+b]) Tan[phi/2]))/((Sqrt[a]-Sqrt[a+b]) Sqrt[(-a+b) (2 a+b+2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b])])])/(b (3 Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[a+b]))-(2 Sqrt[(-a+b) (2 a+b-2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b])] (b-2 (a+Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b])) ArcTan[(b (Sqrt[a]+(Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[a+b]) Tan[phi/2]))/((Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[a+b]) Sqrt[(-a+b) (2 a+b-2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[a+b])])])/(b (-3 Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[a+b])))/(4 a^(3/2)),phi],{a+b>0,b-a>0}]


FullSimplify[D[-((Sqrt[-a+b] ArcTan[Sqrt[a/(-a+b)] (Cos[phi]+Sin[phi])])/(2 a^(3/2))),phi],{a+b>0,b-a>0}]
```

Answer (score -3):

note that ; this relation is always true, see below
$$arctan(\frac{1}{2})+arctan(\frac{1}{3})=arctan(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}})\\arctan1=\frac{\pi}{4} $$but $$ arctan(2)+arctan(3)\neq arctan(\frac{2+3}{1-2.3})=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$it is because $$arctan(\frac{1}{2}),arctan(\frac{1}{2})<\frac{\pi}{2}$$but $$arctan(2),arctan(3)>\frac{\pi}{2}$$so sum of two term can not be $$-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: true is :$$arctan(2)+arctan(3)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.